# In apache - are php files read from disk each time they are called?

Tags: php, apache, optimization, io, hard-drive

I think it's a pretty big bottleneck for big sites? Is there a way to store them in memory?

Answer (score 2):

Yes PHP files are by default read and executed every page request.

You should look into something like [APC](http://www.php.net/apc/), [Zend Accelerator](http://pecl.php.net/package/ZendOpcache), another PHP opcode cache

You may already have these installed, however most of the time they will need some edits to PHP.INI to get them doing their job.